# Keep getting error "PAYMENTTABS_LINEITEM_AMOUNT_IS_MISSING"

Tags: docusignapi

Has anyone tried to change the "fixed amount" of a "payment item" using the DocuSign rest API?

I'm using a template that's been designed and setup via the DocuSign web page.

The template consists of 2 template roles, one of which is the "Customer".  It contains a payment item in which I would like to pre-fill the dollar amount, payment description item code, and payment description item details.

I found this in the documentation under 'formulaTabs':

```
"<paymentDetails>" +
    "<lineItems>" +
        "<paymentLineItem>" +
            "<amountReference>\\*txtPayment</amountReference>" +
            "<description>" + polNum + "</description>" +
            "<itemCode>" + custId + "</itemCode>" +
        "</paymentLineItem>" +
    "</lineItems>" +
"</paymentDetails>" +
```

but, I'm not sure where to place it, I've tried using it within

```
<envelopeDefinition> </envelopeDefinition>
```

and

```
<text> </text>
```

But, I keep coming up with a `PAYMENTTABS_LINEITEM_AMOUNT_IS_MISSING` error.

I have a text field on the template labeled `txtPayment` (which I don't really need).

The payment item is labeled `txtPaymentItem`.

I'm open to using other means if necessary.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am hoping that you are able to use Payment using WEBApp but struggling in using API, so the correct JSON structure to use DocuSignPayment API is,

```
"formulaTabs": [{
                "ConcealValueOnDocument": "false",
                "Formula": "([PaymentItem1]) * 100",
                "IsPaymentAmount": "false",
                "Locked": "true",
                "Name": "paymentsFormulaTab",
                "PaymentDetails": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "gatewayAccountId": "a7dcd60d-d963-4a81-bc72-68b71aad2062",
                    "lineItems": [{
                            "amountReference": "PaymentItem1",
                            "description": "951900;Tims 6.2;4444;1002",
                            "itemCode": "base",
                            "name": "salesDeposit"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Required": "true",
                "RoundDecimalPlaces": "2"
            }
        ],
"numberTabs": [{
                "FontColor": "DarkRed",
                "IsPaymentAmount": "true",
                "Locked": "true",
                "TabLabel": "PaymentItem1",
                "Value": "2500.00"
            }
        ]
```

If you see above JSON structure, it has two tabs, formula and Number Tab and formula Tab uses the Number Tab reference. In this case, it refers to PaymentItem1. Hope above JSON will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I am able to use Payment via web app but struggling in using API.  I was able to get everything working using API, but, the payment amount was fixed and I need it to be entered via API.

Comment: I tried using the `amountReference` technique you referenced above, but, couldn't figure out how to create a `numberTab` via the web app.  All I see is `text` or `formula`, so I tried using a `text` and formatted it as a number.  Is that correct?

Comment: Are you able to see Payment Item tab on tagging page using WEBApp?  and are you using new DocuSign Payments?

Comment: Yes, I see a Payment Item in the web app and yes I think I'm using the new DocuSign Payments.  I really just want a single fixed payment item where I can set a fixed amount.

Comment: Using API, You enter payment amount in numbertabs and that numbertab's tablabel is referenced in formulatab. Can you please share your complete request which you have tried.

Comment: I've tried several things, but, nothing seems to be working.  I don't know how to add a numberTab to my template using the web app.  If it's not in the template then the API just seems to ignore it.  I can add a paymentTab to my template, but, then I can't change the fixed amount using the API.

Comment: While creating Template, after adding PaymentItem Tab, select "Signer Entered" option under Payment Amount and put a value as 0. Then read that template and it will have number tab, after getting tab label, below code will create an envelope with value of 550 USD: `"tabs": {
        "numberTabs": [
          {
            "locked": "true",
            "tabLabel": "PaymentCustom 4533d9ce-eae5-4c12-81cd-ecdfee79970d",
            "value": "550"
          }
        ]
      }`   where PaymentCustom 4533d9ce-eae5-4c12-81cd-ecdfee79970d is the numbertab as available from template.

Comment: That worked!  Thanks, Amit.  Do you know how I can edit the payment details and the payment line item?

Comment: I tried to accept your answer but my reputation appears to be too low :-(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Amit K Bist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3530898/amit-k-bist) this worked to update a `payment item` tab after it's dropped into a template.

When creating a Template, add your Payment Item, select "Signer Entered" option under Payment Amount and put a value of 0.

Then capture the data label from the Payment Item.  It should look similar to this: `PaymentCustom 5e7e552c-2d0e-4364-b4d2-bb1784330191`

Then add this to your request body:

```
"<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
    "<status>sent</status>" +
    "<emailSubject>Turner Pest Control - Termite Bond Quote</emailSubject>" +
    "<templateId>" + templateId + "</templateId>" +
    "<templateRoles>" +
        "<templateRole>" +
            "<name>" + custName + "</name>" +
            "<email>" + custEmail + "</email>" +
            "<roleName>Customer</roleName>" +
            "<tabs>" +
                "<numberTabs>" +
                    "<number>" +
                        "<fontColor>DarkRed</fontColor>" +
                        "<locked>true</locked>" +
                        "<tabLabel>PaymentCustom 5e7e552c-2d0e-4364-b4d2-bb1784330191</tabLabel>" +
                        "<value>" + txtPayment + "</value>" +
                    "</number>" +
                "</numberTabs>" +
            "</tabs>" +
        "</templateRole>" +
    "</templateRoles>" +
"</envelopeDefinition>";
```

How a Payment Item gets turned into a number tab is beyond me, but, it works!
I'm still working on updating the payment details via API.  Getting a [Card declined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi5Xi.png) error so I can't confirm if the payment details are getting updated.

Comment: Update:  I got around the Card Declined error by using a Stripe test credit card number https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards