# DocuSign payment item is working via API, but, having trouble entering a payment description

Tags: c#, xml, docusignapi

This is what I've accomplished so far...
1. Created a DocuSign template using their web application.
2. Added a `Payment item` to the template (Stripe is our payment gateway).
3. Created a DocuSign API envelope request, which also adds the payment amount (see below).

> ```
>             string requestBody = 
>                 "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
>                     "<status>sent</status>" +
>                     "<emailSubject>Just A Test</emailSubject>" +
>                     "<templateId>" + templateId + "</templateId>" +
>                     "<templateRoles>" +
>                         "<templateRole>" +
>                             "<name>" + custName + "</name>" +
>                             "<email>" + custEmail + "</email>" +
>                             "<roleName>Customer</roleName>" +
>                             "<tabs>" +
>                                 "<textTabs>" +
>                                     "<text>" +
>                                         "<tabLabel>\\*txtPropAddr</tabLabel>" +
>                                         "<value>" + txtPropAddr + "</value>" +
>                                     "</text>" +
>                                     "<text>" +
>                                         "<tabLabel>\\*txtPropCity</tabLabel>" +
>                                         "<value>" + txtPropCity.TrimEnd() + "</value>" +
>                                     "</text>" +
>                                     "<text>" +
>                                         "<tabLabel>\\*txtPropZip</tabLabel>" +
>                                         "<value>" + txtPropZip + "</value>" +
>                                     "</text>" +
>                                 "</textTabs>" +
>                                 "<numberTabs>" +
>                                     "<number>" +
>                                         "<fontColor>DarkRed</fontColor>" +
>                                         "<locked>true</locked>" +
>                                         "<tabLabel>PaymentCustom</tabLabel>" +
>                                         "<value>" + txtPayment + "</value>" +
>                                     "</number>" +
>                                 "</numberTabs>" +
>                             "</tabs>" +
>                         "</templateRole>" +
>                         "<templateRole>" +
>                             "<name>" + repName + "</name>" +
>                             "<email>" + repEmail + "</email>" +
>                             "<roleName>SalesRep</roleName>" +
>                         "</templateRole>" +
>                     "</templateRoles>" +
>                 "</envelopeDefinition>";
> ```

All of this works great!
What I would like to do now, is pass some additional information along with the Stripe payment.
There are 3 properties of the template's `Payment item` we can utilize.
All three are located in the `Payment Description` section [see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EjZ4.png).
1. Item Name
2. Item Code / SKU
3. Item Details
If I hard code these three items in the template and send a payment, the additional information appears under the `Metadata` section of the Stripe payment [see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvLUa.png).

Does anyone know how to accomplish this through the API?

I've tried adding several variations of the following to my HTML with no luck.

```
    "<paymentDetails>" +
        "<lineItems>" +
            "<paymentLineItem>" +
                "<amountReference>PaymentCustom</amountReference>" + 
                "<description>test string 1</description>" +
                "<itemCode>test string 2</itemCode>" +
                "<name>test string 3</name>" +
            "</paymentLineItem>" +
        "</lineItems>" +   
    "</paymentDetails>" +
```

Comment: Pleas check https://stackoverflow.com/a/46457892/3530898, you only asked this linked qs

Comment: Amit K Bist, I'm not using a `formula` tab so I'm not sure where to place the `payment details` XML code.  I've tried putting it under the `number tabs' and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Without formula tab you cannot do it, even DocuSign WEBApp uses formula tab to put the payment details. Payment API will not work if you don't use formula tab.

Comment: I'm going to disagree with you a little.  I've gotten the Payment Item to work just fine with my code above.  Once the signer completes the document a separate payment form pops up.  The customer enters their payment information into the form and clicks send.  The payment is then sent to our Stripe account.  All that works great.  I'll try replacing the `numberTab` with a `formulaTab` in the code above and see if that allows me to add some additional payment details.

Comment: You would have setup PaymentItem tab in your template which you are referring "<templateId>" + templateId + "</templateId>" in your code. What PaymentItem tab does is it adds Formula and number tab in the background, to confirm it if you run API to get all tabs of recipients in your envelope, you will be surprised to see that formula tab is present and no PaymentItem tab is present

Comment: Thanks, @AmitKBist  I've looked at all the tabs for the recipient, and I see the background formula tab that was added by the `payment item`.  I'm now capturing the formula _tabLabel_, and using it to try and modify the _formulaTab_.  Now, I'm getting a **Input string was not in a correct format** error.  I've tried several different iterations with no luck.

Comment: Update:  I've gotten around the **Input string was not in a correct format** error.  I must have been missing a required field or something like that.  But, I'm now starting to feel like the payment details can NOT be changed via the API.  I'm not getting any errors, and everything else works just fine, but, the payment details still don't change from what's in the template.

Comment: Can you share what you have in your template and what you want to update while creating an envelope, I can try to create JSON Request for you. If possible download your template and send me at docusign.sso@gmail.com

Comment: @AmitKBist email coming soon, Thanks!

Comment: Sure, add comment here once you have sent an email

Comment: @AmitKBist email was sent last night...

Comment: Sure, will check and get back to you, got swamped with some urgent work.

Comment: Mike, I have sent an email with the solution

Comment: Thanks to @AmitKBist I've been able to update the payment description (Item Name, Item Code, Item Details).  See my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

I would use xml linq for the xml.  See code below.  I used a few different techniques for generating the xml.  I wasn't sure where to add the payments detail.  I can modify if necessary.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int templateId = 123;
            string custName = "john";
            string custEmail = "abc@def.com";
            string txtPropAddr = "123 main st.";
            string txtPropCity = "city";
            int txtPropZip = 12345;
            decimal txtPayment = 1.00M;
            string repName = "john";
            string repEmail = "abc@def.com";

            string requestBody = "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\"></envelopeDefinition>";

            XElement requestBodyElement = XElement.Parse(requestBody);
            XNamespace ns = requestBodyElement.GetDefaultNamespace();

            requestBodyElement.Add(new object[] {
                new XElement(ns + "status", "sent"),
                new XElement(ns + "emailSubject", "Just A Test"),
                new XElement(ns + "templateId", templateId),
                new XElement(ns + "templateRoles", new object[] {
                    new XElement(ns + "templateRole", new object[] {
                        new XElement(ns + "name", custName), 
                        new XElement(ns + "email", custEmail),
                        new XElement(ns + "roleName", "Customer"),
                        new XElement(ns + "tabs", new object[] {
                            new XElement(ns + "textTabs", new object[] {
                                new XElement(ns + "text", new object[] {
                                    new XElement(ns + "tabLabel", "\\*txtPropAddr"),
                                    new XElement(ns + "value", txtPropAddr)
                                }),
                                new XElement(ns + "text", new object[] {
                                    new XElement(ns + "tabLabel", "\\*txtPropCity"),
                                    new XElement(ns + "value", txtPropCity.TrimEnd())
                                }),
                                new XElement(ns + "text", new object[] {
                                    new XElement(ns + "tabLabel", "\\*txtPropZip"),
                                    new XElement(ns + "value", txtPropZip)
                                })
                            }),
                            new XElement(ns + "numberTabs",
                                new XElement(ns + "number", new object[] {
                                    new XElement(ns + "fontColor", "DarkRed"),
                                    new XElement(ns + "locked", true),
                                    new XElement(ns + "tabLabel", "PaymentCustom"),
                                    new XElement(ns + "value", txtPayment)
                                })
                            })
                        })
                    }),
                    new XElement(ns + "templateRole", new object[] {
                        new XElement(ns + "name", repName), 
                        new XElement(ns + "email", repEmail),
                        new XElement(ns + "roleName", "SalesRep")
                    })
                })
            });

            XElement paymentDetails = new XElement(ns + "paymentDetails",
                new XElement(ns + "paymentDetails",
                    new XElement(ns + "lineItems",
                        new XElement(ns + "paymentLineItem", new object[] {
                            new XElement(ns + "amountReference", "PaymentCustom"), 
                            new XElement(ns + "description", "test string 1"),
                            new XElement(ns + "itemCode", "test string 2"),
                            new XElement(ns + "name", "test string 3")
                        })
                    )
               )
            );

            requestBodyElement.Add(paymentDetails);


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but, my XML wasn't the problem.  I don't know where to put the payments detail either.  I've tried it several times in different places and nothing worked.

Comment: I know the xml was bad, it is just not the way of creating an xml using string.  My code properly adds the paymentDetails to the xml.l

Comment: OK, I'll convert my string and see what happens.  Thanks!

Comment: RESULTS: The code above simply adds a `paymentDetails` element to the end of the XML string.  That didn't work.  Still, no payment details showing up in the Stripe payment.

Comment: I really don't know the tool.  Did some searching on Docusign webpage which states they have great documentation.  I don't agree.  See following webpage.  It looks like you can download a template.  Look at pulldown with Green Arrow. https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/requesting-payments-along-with-signatures

Comment: I agree, their documentation is pretty good for using the web application and interface, but, not for using the API.  The API documentation appears to be a little old.  I am utilizing an envelope template which is very nice.  You can layout your document using a nice GUI, and then fill in data fields and send the envelope using the API.  Thanks for looking into this problem for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create DocuSign template via the website.
2. Add a `text` field to the template, set data label, set validation to numbers. Setting the validation to number actually turns the field into a number tab.
3. Add a `payment item` field to the template, select your payment gateway, change the payment amount to a formula, edit the formula and select your `text` field data label from step 2. Actually, creates two hidden `formulaTabs`in the template.
4. GetRecipientId() - Captures the template role recipient id number, used when updating the number tab.
5. CreateEnvelope() - Updates `templateRoles`, `textTabs`, and `numberTabs` on the template.
6. GetFormulaTabIds() - Captures `formulaTab` id numbers, used when updating the two hidden formula tabs created in step 3.
7. UpdateEnvelopeFormulas() - Adds payment description.
8. UpdateEnvelopeStatus() - Sends DocuSign email.

*I know there's a better way to create an XML string, but, I feel it's overly complicated. I simply used GetEnvelopeRecipientTabs() to create an XML doc, then cut and paste what's needed into my code, very easy...*

```
    // Enter your credentials
    public static string username = "guid";
    public static string password = "string";
    public static string integratorKey = "guid";
    public static string loginEndpoint = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi";// for production change to www.docusign.net/restapi
    public static string gatewayAccountId = "guid";
    public static string recipId = null;
    public static string PaymentReceiptTabId = null;
    public static string PaymentFormulaTabId = null;
    public static string templateId = "guid";
    public static string baseURL = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/#######"

    GetRecipientId();

    public static string CreateEnvelope()
    {
        string RV = null;
        try
        {
            string url = baseURL + "/envelopes";
            string xmlRequestBody =
                "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
                    "<status>created</status>" +
                      "<emailSubject>Turner Pest Control - Termite Bond Quote</emailSubject>" +
                      "<templateId>" + templateId + "</templateId>" +
                      "<templateRoles>" +
                        "<templateRole>" +
                          "<name>" + custName + "</name>" +
                          "<email>" + custEmail + "</email>" +
                          "<roleName>Customer</roleName>" +
                          "<tabs>" +
                            "<textTabs>" +
                              "<text>" +
                                "<tabLabel>txtPropAddr</tabLabel>" +
                                "<value>" + txtPropAddr.TrimEnd() + "</value>" +
                              "</text>" +
                              "<text>" +
                                "<tabLabel>txtPropZip</tabLabel>" +
                                "<value>" + txtPropZip + "</value>" +
                              "</text>" +
                            "</textTabs>" +
                            "<numberTabs>" +
                                "<number>" +
                                    "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
                                    "<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>" +
                                    "<recipientId>" + recipId + "</recipientId>" +
                                    "<tabLabel>TPCPaymentCustom</tabLabel>" +
                                    "<locked>true</locked>" +
                                    "<required>false</required>" +
                                    "<value>" + txtPayment + "</value>" +
                                    "<isPaymentAmount>false</isPaymentAmount>" +
                                "</number>" +
                            "</numberTabs>" +
                          "</tabs>" +
                        "</templateRole>" +
                        "<templateRole>" +
                          "<name>" + repName + "</name>" +
                          "<email>" + repEmail + "</email>" +
                          "<roleName>SalesRep</roleName>" +
                        "</templateRole>" +
                    "</templateRoles>" +
                "</envelopeDefinition>";
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xmlRequestBody);
            HttpWebRequest request = initializeRequest(url, "POST", doc.OuterXml, username, password, integratorKey);
            using (HttpWebResponse resp = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmldoc.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());
                xmldoc.Save("C:\\Temp\\DocuSign\\CreateEnvelopeResponse.xml");// FOR TESTING ONLY
                XmlNodeList xnList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("envelopeSummary");
                foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
                {
                    string status = xn["status"].InnerText;
                    if (status == "created")
                    {
                        string envelopeId = xn["envelopeId"].InnerText;
                        GetFormulaTabIds();
                        if (UpdateEnvelopeFormulas())
                        {
                            if (UpdateEnvelopeStatus())
                            {
                                RV = envelopeId;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            using (WebResponse response = e.Response)
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    string text = new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();
                    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(text);
                    SmtpEmailSend(httpResponse.StatusCode);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SmtpEmailSend("CreateEnvelope() Error!");
        }
        return RV;
    }

    public static bool UpdateEnvelopeFormulas()
    {
        bool RV = false;
        try
        {
            string url = baseURL + "/envelopes/" + envelopeId + "/recipients/1/tabs";
            string xmlRequestBody =
                "<tabs xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
                    "<formulaTabs xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/API_REST.Models\">" +
                        "<a:formulaTab>" +
                            "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
                            "<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>" +
                            "<recipientId>1</recipientId>" +
                            "<tabId>" + PaymentReceiptTabId + "</tabId>" +
                            "<tabLabel>PaymentReceipt c6d38477-62a4-4a03-adc1-671456278ecf</tabLabel>" +
                            "<locked>true</locked>" +
                            "<required>true</required>" +
                            "<a:formula>([PaymentFormula 4354e223-fb2e-44ed-81e4-385b40eb81f6]) * 100</a:formula>" +
                            "<a:hidden>true</a:hidden>" +
                            "<a:isPaymentAmount>false</a:isPaymentAmount>" +
                            "<a:paymentDetails>" +
                                "<currencyCode>USD</currencyCode>" +
                                "<gatewayAccountId>" + gatewayAccountId + "</gatewayAccountId>" +
                                "<gatewayDisplayName>Stripe</gatewayDisplayName>" +
                                "<gatewayName>stripe</gatewayName>" +
                                "<lineItems xmlns:b=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/API_REST.Models.v2.payments\">" +
                                    "<b:paymentLineItem>" +
                                        "<b:amountReference>PaymentFormula 4354e223-fb2e-44ed-81e4-385b40eb81f6</b:amountReference>" +
                                        "<b:description>CustNum[" + custNo + "]</b:description>" +
                                        "<b:itemCode>PolicyNum[" + policyNum + "]</b:itemCode>" +
                                        "<b:name>" + warrantyType + "</b:name>" +
                                    "</b:paymentLineItem>" +
                                "</lineItems>" +
                                "<status>new</status>" +
                            "</a:paymentDetails>" +
                            "<a:roundDecimalPlaces>0</a:roundDecimalPlaces>" +
                        "</a:formulaTab>" +
                        "<a:formulaTab>" +
                            "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
                            "<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>" +
                            "<recipientId>1</recipientId>" +
                            "<tabId>" + PaymentFormulaTabId + "</tabId>" +
                            "<tabLabel>PaymentFormula 4354e223-fb2e-44ed-81e4-385b40eb81f6</tabLabel>" +
                            "<locked>true</locked>" +
                            "<required>true</required>" +
                            "<a:formula>[TPCPaymentCustom]</a:formula>" +
                            "<a:hidden>true</a:hidden>" +
                            "<a:isPaymentAmount>false</a:isPaymentAmount>" +
                            "<a:roundDecimalPlaces>2</a:roundDecimalPlaces>" +
                        "</a:formulaTab>" +
                    "</formulaTabs>" +
                "</tabs>";
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xmlRequestBody);
            HttpWebRequest request = initializeRequest(url, "PUT", doc.OuterXml, username, password, integratorKey);
            using (HttpWebResponse resp = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();// FOR TESTING ONLY
                xmldoc.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());// FOR TESTING ONLY
                xmldoc.Save("C:\\Temp\\DocuSign\\RecipientTabUpdateResponse.xml");// FOR TESTING ONLY
                RV = true;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            using (WebResponse response = e.Response)
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    string text = new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();
                    SmtpEmailSend(httpResponse.StatusCode);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SmtpEmailSend("UpdateEnvelopeFormula() Error!");
        }
        return RV;
    }

    public static bool UpdateEnvelopeStatus()
    {
        bool RV = false;
        try
        {
            string url = baseURL + "/envelopes/" + envelopeId;
            string xmlRequestBody =
                "<envelope xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
                    "<status>sent</status>" +
                "</envelope>";
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xmlRequestBody);
            HttpWebRequest request = initializeRequest(url, "PUT", doc.OuterXml, username, password, integratorKey);
            using (HttpWebResponse resp = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();// FOR TESTING ONLY
                xmldoc.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());// FOR TESTING ONLY
                xmldoc.Save("C:\\Temp\\DocuSign\\EnvelopeStatusUpdateResponse.xml");// FOR TESTING ONLY
                RV = true;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            using (WebResponse response = e.Response)
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    string text = new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();
                    SmtpEmailSend(httpResponse.StatusCode);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SmtpEmailSend("UpdateEnvelopeStatus() Error!");
        }
        return RV;
    }

    //***************************************************
    // --- HELPER FUNCTIONS ---
    //***************************************************

    public static HttpWebRequest initializeRequest(string url, string method, string body, string email, string password, string intKey)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = method;
        addRequestHeaders(request, email, password, intKey);
        if (body != null)
            addRequestBody(request, body);
        return request;
    }

    public static void addRequestHeaders(HttpWebRequest request, string email, string password, string intKey)
    {
        string authenticateStr =
            "<DocuSignCredentials>" +
                "<Username>" + username + "</Username>" +
                "<Password>" + password + "</Password>" +
                "<IntegratorKey>" + integratorKey + "</IntegratorKey>" +
                "</DocuSignCredentials>";
        request.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authenticateStr);
        request.Accept = "application/xml";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
    }

    public static void addRequestBody(HttpWebRequest request, string requestBody)
    {
        // create byte array out of request body and add to the request object
        byte[] body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(body, 0, requestBody.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
    }

    public static string getResponseBody(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        // read the response stream into a local string
        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        return responseText;
    }

    public static void GetEnvelopeRecipientTabs()
    {
        string url = baseURL + "/envelopes/" + envelopeId + "/recipients?include_tabs=true";
        HttpWebRequest request = initializeRequest(url, "GET", null, username, password, integratorKey);
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        using (HttpWebResponse resp = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            xmldoc.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());
            xmldoc.Save("C:\\Temp\\DocuSign\\EnvelopeRecipientsTabs.xml");// FOR TESTING ONLY
        }
    }

    public static void GetRecipientId()
    {
        string url = baseURL + "/templates/" + templateId + "/recipients";
        HttpWebRequest request = initializeRequest(url, "GET", null, username, password, integratorKey);
        using (HttpWebResponse resp = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());
            xmldoc.Save("C:\\Temp\\DocuSign\\TemplateRecipients.xml");// FOR TESTING ONLY
            XmlNodeList xnList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("signer");
            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                string roleName = xn["roleName"].InnerText;
                if (roleName == "Customer")
                {
                    // Get customer's recipientId
                    recipId = xn["recipientId"].InnerText;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void GetFormulaTabIds()
    {
        string url = baseURL + "/envelopes/" + envelopeId + "/recipients/1/tabs";
        HttpWebRequest request = initializeRequest(url, "GET", null, username, password, integratorKey);
        using (HttpWebResponse resp = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());
            xmldoc.Save("C:\\Temp\\DocuSign\\RecipientOneTabs.xml");// FOR TESTING ONLY
            XmlNodeList xnList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("a:formulaTab");
            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                // Gets the tabId's for hidden formula tabs, which get inserted into the envelope, 
                // when a "Payment Item" is dropped on a template, and the Payment Amount is set to a Formula.
                string tabLabel = xn["tabLabel"].InnerText;
                switch (tabLabel.Substring(0, 14))
                {
                    case "PaymentReceipt":
                        PaymentReceiptTabId = xn["tabId"].InnerText;
                        break;
                    case "PaymentFormula":
                        PaymentFormulaTabId = xn["tabId"].InnerText;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

A **HUGE** thanks goes out to `Amit K Bist` for helping me solve this issue!